# SSIS Batch Processing

Tags: sql-server, ssis, bulkinsert, batch-processing

Can anyone please tell me how to perform a simple batch process in SSIS?

I know how to do such a thing using T-SQL and/or .NET code but what I wish to do is to use the SSIS GUI to do this entirely.  I am not sure if it is possible and all I can find on Google are over complicated solutions.

To explain a bit more - I am reading from a flat file and I want to insert its entire contents into a Sql Server table.  Pretty simple huh...  But I want to do it 50,000 records at a time.  I expect this to be as simple as setting a property somewhere or at the most using some kind of loop tool from the toolbox.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. It is a property of the Data Flow task.

Right click on the task, click on the "Properties..." command, look for the `DefaultBufferMaxRows` property and set the desired value.

References [@MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141031(v=sql.100).aspx).

[image]

Comment: Yes I have set this, but there is still something I don't understand.  The reason I wanted to do this in the first place is to consume as little memory as possible - but my RAM usage still climbs...

Comment: @Shumii. Shutdown the SSIS execution and read the base line memory usage. Start the SSIS task and keep track of the memory usage. There are a lot of tips in the article I linked in my post. Besides setting the record numbers, you can set up the memory buffer size too. Picture added.